# how to transform sql command with max function into int value in ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, function, max

I have this code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select max(ID) from otazky", connection);  
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  

int id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
```

I read that max function doesn't return row from SQL but just 1 value, how to get that value into asp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it an alias, something like `MaxId`:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select max(ID) AS MaxId from otazky", connection);
```

Then you can select it with this alias.

```
int id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MaxId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SELECT query as follows:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(ID) as MAX FROM otazky", connection);  
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  

int id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MAX"));
```

You have to give a column name alias (using AS) to any aggregate SQL function that you use in your query.